# Error while opening existing PowerPoint file through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am using the following code for opening a new PowerPoint presentation but it gives an error which I am not able to figure out the solution of.

```
strPresPath = "C:\Users\MAHE\Documents\template.ppt"
Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
```

and the error being

```
"Method 'open' of object 'Presentation' failed"
```

Also if any one can help in adding new slide to the PowerPoint would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem in the code. But you could try using a reference to "Microsoft PowerPoint XX.X Object Library":

The code would be like this instead:

```
Dim oPPTApp As New PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @gizlmeier's suggestion, try this:

```
strPresPath = "C:\Users\MAHE\Documents\template.ppt"
Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

' Verify that the PPT object was created successfully
If oPPTApp is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "Unable to create PowerPoint object"
   Exit Sub ' or function
Else
   Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
End if
```

That'll at least prove that the PPT object has been created successfully (or that it hasn't been).